# sort hash key in perl with key being tab separated

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I have a hash of arrays (perl) whose key is a string joined by tabs.
This is how the key of the hash looks like

```
chr"\t"fivep"\t"threep"\t"strand  # separated on tab
```

If the hash is named `%output`

I want to sort the keys of this hash such that first the sort is done on chr, then on fivep and then on threep.

I tried the below code for sorting:

```
foreach my $k(sort keys %output){
    print join("\t",$k,@{$output{$k}}),"\n";    
}
```

This sort only the chr but I want to sort fivep after it and then threep.

How can I perform that?

Comment: Not a fully baked solution, but when I'm trying to sort similar data, I have found `Sort::Versions` to be quite handy and able to sort these kinds of strings easily. I usually will use it to sort something like `chr1:12345:T>A` and it handles this well.  Might be a simple thing to try first?

Comment: Have you considering changing the key itself when you populate the hash? Then, your code would work as is.

Comment: Yes I have. May be something like this hash of arrays `@{$output{$chr}->{$fivep}->{$threep}->{$strand}}`. Then use foreach loops to print the output. It works well.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to recommend you do a transform on your keys and then do the custom sort.

```
for my $k (
    map { $_->[0] } # pull out the original key
    sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] || $a->[2] cmp $b->[2] || $a->[3] cmp $b->[3] } # do the actual sort
    map { [ $_, split /\t/, $_, -1 ] } # split the keys and make the transform
    keys %output
) {
     print join "\t", $k, @output{$k};
}
```

You can factor the `sort` code block into it's own function if it's overly complex or this process needs to be reused in more places in the code, as well, then just give the function for `sort`.

Comment: Should probably be `split /\t/, $_, -1` instead of `split /\t/, $_`. Empty fields are quite common in TSV files.

Answer (score 3):

I think https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Maker does what you want. The following code should work for you.

```
use Sort::Key::Maker custom_sort => qw(str str str);
my @sorted = custom_sort { (split /\t/, $_, -1)[ 0 .. 2 ] } keys %output;
```

Comment: Thank you @ikegami. I've updated the answer with your suggestions.